# Dynamic arrayjob size AwsBatchOperator

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, aws-batch

I have a compute job I wish to scale dynamically according to charge.

Since the compute is done on AWS batch, I want to use the array_size parameter, here is how I do it with the AwsBatchOperator in airflow :

```
task_batch = AwsBatchOperator(
        job_name=job_name,
        job_definition=job_def,
        job_queue=job_queue,
        array_properties={'size': " {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='compute_arraysize') | int }}" },
        task_id="task_to_scale",
    )
```

However, as far as I understood the documentation, the array_properties parameter isn't "templated" (not sure why though), so my template is not rendered and I have this error :

```
Invalid type for parameter arrayProperties.size, value:  {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='compute_arraysize') | int }}, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'int'>
```

How can I fix this and decide the size dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by feruzzi [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/26805) will solve the issue and will be available in

[apache-airflow-providers-amazon>6.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/#description)

However you can still solve your issue in your current version by adding the needed parameter to template fields:

```
class MyBatchOperator(BatchOperator):

    template_fields = (
        "array_properties",
    ) + BatchOperator.template_fields
```

Then you can do:

```
task_batch = MyBatchOperator(
        job_name=job_name,
        job_definition=job_def,
        job_queue=job_queue,
        array_properties={'size': " {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='compute_arraysize') | int }}" },
        task_id="task_to_scale",
    )
```

Comment: Better Answer ^^^

Yup, good call, a wrapper operator like that would be a much cleaner way to do it if you don't want to open the source code.

Answer (score 2):

The easy local fix will be to add `"array_properties"` to the `template_fields` sequence on line 104 of the [AwsBatchOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/batch.py#L104).  I will put in a pull request to implement it in the Airflow code, but it will take some time for that to make its way to you.

[EDIT] The PR to fix it permanently is [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/26805) if you want to follow its progress.  It should be in the next Amazon Provider Package release, whenever that gets published.

Comment: This is also what I thought initially but isn’t it strange it is not already like this ?

Comment: Not specifically.   Lots of operators are missing some or all template fields for one reason or another.  It's something that folks are slowly picking away at, but it's a boring task so volunteers are not lining up to do it.  Airflow accepts PRs from the public, if you feel like making a dent in that some time, or if you ruin into it again and want to make the fix yourself. 

Comment: Added a link to the PR in the answer for anyone who wants to follow it along and see when it gets merged.